# Valheim Dedicated Server Linux Crossplay Issue

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run a Valheim Server in a Docker Container but I'm having the following error when I try to boot with the `-crossplay` flag

```
18.05 14:25:42 [Server] INFO Mono path[0] = '/valheim_server_Data/Managed'
18.05 14:25:42 [Server] INFO Mono config path = '/valheim_server_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
18.05 14:25:42 [Server] INFO Preloaded 'libsteam_api.so'
18.05 14:25:42 [Server] INFO Unable to preload the following plugins:
18.05 14:25:42 [Server] INFO libparty.so
```

The `libparty.so` is required for Crossplay and with this the server is unusable.

From some research I found suggestions to add the `libpulse-dev` package to the environment. Which I have done however now I get the following error instead:

```
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO Mono path[0] = '/valheim_server_Data/Managed'
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO Mono config path = '/valheim_server_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO Caught fatal signal - signo:11 code:1 errno:0 addr:0x20
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO Obtained 23 stack frames.
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #0 0x007f6ef91ae140 in funlockfile
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #1 0x007f6ef3a1cf00 in BumblelionLogger::TryToLoadConfigurationFile()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #2 0x007f6ef3a1ccf8 in BumblelionLogger::BumblelionLogger()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #3 0x007f6ef3a1d890 in BumblelionLogger::GetInstance()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #4 0x007f6ef3a1cc16 in DbgLogAreaFlags_FnInOut
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #5 0x007f6ef3a34d99 in OutstandingPlayFabRequestManager::OutstandingRequest::OutstandingRequest()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #6 0x007f6ef3a34c1d in OutstandingPlayFabRequestManager::OutstandingRequestList::OutstandingRequestList()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #7 0x007f6ef3a3a6cb in _GLOBAL__sub_I_PlayFabServiceManagerImpl.cpp
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #8 0x007f6efb25dfe2 in _dl_rtld_di_serinfo
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #9 0x007f6efb25e0e9 in _dl_rtld_di_serinfo
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #10 0x007f6ef90fcaed in _dl_catch_exception
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #11 0x007f6efb262058 in _dl_find_dso_for_object
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #12 0x007f6ef90fca90 in _dl_catch_exception
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #13 0x007f6efb2618fa in _dl_find_dso_for_object
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #14 0x007f6ef8fc2258 in (Unknown)
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #15 0x007f6ef90fca90 in _dl_catch_exception
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #16 0x007f6ef90fcb4f in _dl_catch_error
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #17 0x007f6ef8fc2a65 in dlerror
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #18 0x007f6ef8fc22e4 in dlopen
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #19 0x007f6efa242bb2 in PreloadPlugins()
18.05 14:33:40 [Server] INFO #20 0x007f6efa24098a in PlayerMain(int, char**)
```

Docker image is based on `debian:bullseye-slim`

Comment: Questions must be related to programming.

Comment: I'm having an issue within a Docker image which is something I've seen people post many times before and is accepted?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here.